# Advantage of backing up to multiple files?

Tags: db2-luw

I come from a Sybase background, and with it, if a backup to one file took 20 minutes, a backup to two files would take 10 minutes (plus a bit of overhead), four files would take 5 minutes (plus a bit more overhead), etc.  I expected to see the same results with DB2 but it doesn't seem to be reducing the overall backup time at all.  While not optimal, in both the Sybase and DB2 tests the files were all being written to the same filesystem.   Am I misunderstanding what the multi-file backup achieves in DB2?   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you take a look at the [BACKUP DATABASE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0001933.html) syntax and options you will notice that Db2 supports several storage targets (with respective options) as well as options on how the database data is read. The backup process consists of reading the relevant data from the database and writing it to the backup device.

For the reading part, there are options like `BUFFER` and `PARALLELISM` that impact performance and throughput. By default, if not specified by the user, Db2 tries to come up with good values. This is something you could look into.

Are you compressing or encrypting the backup file? Are you writing the backup to the same file system as your database is in? That would be more to consider.

Comment: Looking at the PARALLELISM option it seems that backup will (by default) choose a number based on the number of tablespaces that can be read in parallel.  Can I assume if I only specify one file for the backup that parallelism won't be employed?  Can I also assume that if I have a database with two equally sized tablespaces, and I specify two directories on the backup, that it will do those two in parallel, cutting the time in half?

Comment: We do compress our backups and they are NOT written to the same filesystem(s) that the databases reside on.

Comment: Maybe I should have originally asked "What characteristics of a database make it a good candidate to achieve decreased backup times when switching from a single-file to multi-file backup?".

Comment: You could withdraw your question and ask over in the dba forum on stack exchange. Are you using TSM or any other storage infrastructure? What is the purpose of the backups? Snapshot, online, offline? ...

Comment: That shows you how well I understand Stack Exchange's setup.  I assumed when I clicked "Ask a question" and tagged it as db2, that it was, in affect, getting to the db2 audience.   There's a DBA forum that's separate from where I'm posting?

Comment: To answer your questions, well sort of,  it's not the specifics of any particular backup I'm trying to improve, but since DB2 provides the ability to write to multiple files (preferably in parallel), I was assuming that was to shorten the duration of a backup operation.   I'm just not seeing that benefit, so I was wondering what database characteristics make it a good candidate to see that benefit.  Thanks for your responses BTW.  I do appreciate them. :-)